# Elasticsearch long GC

Tags: elasticsearch

Running 1.5.2

Per Server specs: 2x8 (Hyperthreaded) 32 cores, 128GB RAM, 5.2TB SSDS, Windows 2008

Running 4 node cluster Elasticsearch default settings except where noted.

```
#Since day 1 configured to use 30gb, using doc values but expect quite a bit of sorting.
ES_HEAP_SIZE=30gb

#Not really starting multiple nodes on same machine forgot to turn this off.
cluster.routing.allocation.same_shard.host: true
discovery.zen.minimum_master_nodes: 3
discovery.zen.ping.timeout: 6s
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: true

#Configured the below setting to allow better bulking. Looked at marvel stats, the 512 bulk pool was initially configured since we where bulking into multiple indexes at same time which is no longer the case. It isn't really needed will probably reduce it but I doubt it's the root cause. Now only bulking into single index per bulk request.
{
   "persistent": {
      "threadpool": {
         "bulk": {
            "size": "512",
            "queue_size": "512"
         }
      },
      "indices": {
         "store": {
            "throttle": {
               "max_bytes_per_sec": "200mb"
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "transient": {
      "cluster": {
         "routing": {
            "allocation": {
               "cluster_concurrent_rebalance": "8",
               "node_concurrent_recoveries": "8",
               "node_initial_primaries_recoveries": "16",
               "enable": "all"
            }
         }
      },
      "indices": {
         "recovery": {
            "concurrent_streams": "9",
            "max_bytes_per_sec": "80mb"
         }
      }
   }
}

Index refresh rate is set to 30s and translog threashold to 1000mb
```

With the above settings we were able to bulk index 3500 documents/sec for 2.5 days straight we reached 400 million documents verry stable cluster and running some searches. We are not using field data, we are configured for doc_values though we do expect to do quite a bit of sorting in searches.

At the time of the long GC, we where only doing bulk, no specific searches, nothing else, except marvel open in a browser. Was away not testing searches.

Field data size is about 20mb per node and 150mb for filter cache per node.

Then this hapenned on a single node:

```
[2015-05-14 10:21:43,607][WARN ][monitor.jvm              ] [xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] [gc][old][301536][3170] duration [6.2m], collections [4]/[6.2m], total [6.2m]/[2.1h], memory [28.2gb]->[28.3gb]/[29.8gb], all_pools {[young] [480.3mb]->[406.4mb]/[1.4gb]}{[survivor] [0b]->[191.3mb]/[191.3mb]}{[old] [27.7gb]->[27.8gb]/[28.1gb]}
```

Now the cluster is in Yellow state and balancing the shards.

The latest VM stats:

```
{
   "cluster_name": "xxxx",
   "nodes": {
      "RYl4XN03TNuXFkKfUgm3fQ": {
         "timestamp": 1431626086373,
         "name": "xxxx (10.0.0.xxxx)",
         "transport_address": "inet[/10.0.0.xxxx:9300]",
         "host": "xxxx",
         "ip": [
            "inet[/10.0.0.xxxx:9300]",
            "NONE"
         ],
         "jvm": {
            "timestamp": 1431626085671,
            "uptime_in_millis": 326261959,
            "mem": {
               "heap_used_in_bytes": 27794721128,
               "heap_used_percent": 86,
               "heap_committed_in_bytes": 32011649024,
               "heap_max_in_bytes": 32011649024,
               "non_heap_used_in_bytes": 129160952,
               "non_heap_committed_in_bytes": 131510272,
               "pools": {
                   "young": {
                     "used_in_bytes": 1285037736,
                     "max_in_bytes": 1605304320,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes": 1605304320,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes": 1605304320
                  },
                  "survivor": {
                     "used_in_bytes": 6206720,
                     "max_in_bytes": 200605696,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes": 200605696,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes": 200605696
                  },
                  "old": {
                     "used_in_bytes": 26503476672,
                     "max_in_bytes": 30205739008,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes": 30202301920,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes": 30205739008
                  }
               }
            },
            "threads": {
               "count": 872,
               "peak_count": 4152
            },
            "gc": {
                "collectors": {
                  "young": {
                     "collection_count": 133741,
                     "collection_time_in_millis": 14345888
                  },
                  "old": {
                     "collection_count": 3801,
                     "collection_time_in_millis": 5671656
                  }
               }
            },
            "buffer_pools": {
               "direct": {
                  "count": 2270,
                  "used_in_bytes": 135625370,
                  "total_capacity_in_bytes": 135625370
               },
               "mapped": {
                  "count": 28033,
                  "used_in_bytes": 1222266447033,
                  "total_capacity_in_bytes": 1222266447033
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "GIGmBll-RsO0CIeiRol19Q": {
         "timestamp": 1431626086313,
         "name": "xxxx (10.0.0.xxxx)",
         "transport_address": "inet[/10.0.0.xxxx:9300]",
         "host": "xxxx",
         "ip": [
            "inet[/10.0.0.xxxx:9300]",
            "NONE"
         ],
         "jvm": {
            "timestamp": 1431626086313,
            "uptime_in_millis": 326247220,
            "mem": {
               "heap_used_in_bytes": 26759522704,
               "heap_used_percent": 83,
               "heap_committed_in_bytes": 32011649024,
               "heap_max_in_bytes": 32011649024,
               "non_heap_used_in_bytes": 130322080,
               "non_heap_committed_in_bytes": 132616192,
               "pools": {
                  "young": {
                     "used_in_bytes": 207756720,
                     "max_in_bytes": 1605304320,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes": 1605304320,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes": 1605304320
                  },
                  "survivor": {
                     "used_in_bytes": 34069744,
                     "max_in_bytes": 200605696,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes": 200605696,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes": 200605696
                  },
                  "old": {
                     "used_in_bytes": 26517696240,
                     "max_in_bytes": 30205739008,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes": 30201611848,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes": 30205739008
                  }
               }
            },
            "threads": {
               "count": 884,
               "peak_count": 2855
            },
            "gc": {
               "collectors": {
                  "young": {
                     "collection_count": 132317,
                     "collection_time_in_millis": 14532604
                  },
                  "old": {
                     "collection_count": 3728,
                     "collection_time_in_millis": 6390133
                  }
               }
            },
            "buffer_pools": {
               "direct": {
                  "count": 2301,
                  "used_in_bytes": 136604011,
                  "total_capacity_in_bytes": 136604011
               },
               "mapped": {
                  "count": 28077,
                  "used_in_bytes": 1226500757758,
                  "total_capacity_in_bytes": 1226500757758
               }
            }
         }
      },
      "JNcxaYFTSv20iqAmgpBm2Q": {
         "timestamp": 1431626086599,
         "name": "xxxx (10.0.0.xxxx)",
         "transport_address": "inet[xxxx/10.0.0.xxxx:9300]",
         "host": "xxxx",
         "ip": [
            "inet[xxxx/10.0.0.xxxx:9300]",
            "NONE"
         ],
         "jvm": {
            "timestamp": 1431626086599,
            "uptime_in_millis": 326274817,
            "mem": {
               "heap_used_in_bytes": 12784591992,
               "heap_used_percent": 39,
               "heap_committed_in_bytes": 32011649024,
               "heap_max_in_bytes": 32011649024,
               "non_heap_used_in_bytes": 133812080,
               "non_heap_committed_in_bytes": 135835648,
               "pools": {
                  "young": {
                     "used_in_bytes": 398354208,
                     "max_in_bytes": 1605304320,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes": 1605304320,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes": 1605304320
                  },
                  "survivor": {
                     "used_in_bytes": 84894616,
                     "max_in_bytes": 200605696,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes": 200605696,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes": 200605696
                  },
                  "old": {
                     "used_in_bytes": 12301347344,
                     "max_in_bytes": 30205739008,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes": 30200356360,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes": 30205739008
                  }
               }
            },
            "threads": {
               "count": 897,
               "peak_count": 2319
            },
            "gc": {
               "collectors": {
                  "young": {
                     "collection_count": 132882,
                     "collection_time_in_millis": 14076027
                  },
                  "old": {
                     "collection_count": 3175,
                     "collection_time_in_millis": 7975099
                  }
               }
            },
            "buffer_pools": {
               "direct": {
                  "count": 3094,
                  "used_in_bytes": 165837901,
                  "total_capacity_in_bytes": 165837901
               },
               "mapped": {
                  "count": 16336,
                  "used_in_bytes": 716955739746,
                  "total_capacity_in_bytes": 716955739746
               }
            }
          }
      },
      "BXb5Ek48TTeD87WOM3wqXg": {
         "timestamp": 1431626086497,
         "name": "xxxx (10.0.0.xxxx)",
         "transport_address": "inet[/10.0.0.xxxx:9300]",
         "host": "xxxx",
         "ip": [
            "inet[/10.0.0.xxxx:9300]",
            "NONE"
         ],
         "jvm": {
            "timestamp": 1431626086497,
            "uptime_in_millis": 326255802,
            "mem": {
               "heap_used_in_bytes": 26938475512,
               "heap_used_percent": 84,
               "heap_committed_in_bytes": 32011649024,
               "heap_max_in_bytes": 32011649024,
               "non_heap_used_in_bytes": 137921040,
               "non_heap_committed_in_bytes": 139923456,
               "pools": {
                  "young": {
                     "used_in_bytes": 1469836080,
                     "max_in_bytes": 1605304320,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes": 1605304320,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes": 1605304320
                  },
                  "survivor": {
                     "used_in_bytes": 34356752,
                     "max_in_bytes": 200605696,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes": 200605696,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes": 200605696
                  },
                  "old": {
                     "used_in_bytes": 25434282680,
                     "max_in_bytes": 30205739008,
                     "peak_used_in_bytes": 30201487944,
                     "peak_max_in_bytes": 30205739008
                  }
               }
            },
            "threads": {
               "count": 909,
               "peak_count": 1414
            },
            "gc": {
               "collectors": {
                  "young": {
                      "collection_count": 128613,
                      "collection_time_in_millis": 13985910
                  },
                  "old": {
                     "collection_count": 3582,
                     "collection_time_in_millis": 6905669
                  }
               }
            },
            "buffer_pools": {
               "direct": {
                  "count": 2419,
                  "used_in_bytes": 141681639,
                  "total_capacity_in_bytes": 141681639
               },
               "mapped": {
                  "count": 27785,
                  "used_in_bytes": 1220079289372,
                  "total_capacity_in_bytes": 1220079289372
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you have swapping enabled on your nodes? `mlockall` is `true`? Also, why did you increase the bulk thread pool size? For a node, in your case it should have been 32, by default. Also, note that, even though the long GC took a lot of time, it wasn't able to reclaim anything back.

Comment: I initially increased the bulk pool size because I was doing bulk to multiple indexes at the same time. But that was way before the issue happened. I just forgot to reduce the size back down. The Bulk ops per sec now are 5 even with 4000 documents per bulk. There's no bulk rejections the pool size is at steady 512 and the queue_size at 0. I also managed to get a large GC while doing a scroll search and bulking at same time.

I will try 2 things, reduce my ES_HEAP to half, using doc_values where I can. Maybe try G1GC I know not recommended yet, I'm on JDK 1.8_45.

Mlockall: Nope on Windows 2008

Comment: did these two things work?

Comment: Unfortunately, not running that cluster and it was long time ago :(